# why i can't get the result from lagou this web site by using web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I m using python 3.6.5 and my os system is macOS 10.13.6.

I m learning Web Scraping and I want to catch data from this web site(https://www.lagou.com/jobs/list_python?labelWords=&fromSearch=true&suginput=)

Here is my code:

```py
# encoding: utf-8

import requests
from lxml import etree

def parse_list_page():
    url = 'https://www.lagou.com/jobs/positionAjax.json?city=%E6%B7%B1%E5%9C%B3&needAddtionalResult=false'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537',
        'Host':'www.lagou.com',
        'Referer':'https://www.lagou.com/jobs/list_python?labelWords=&fromSearch=true&suginput=',
        'X-Anit-Forge-Code':'0',
        'X-Anit-Forge-Token':None,
        'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
    }
    data = {
        'first':'false',
        'pn':1,
        'kd':'python',
    }
    response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data)
    print(response.json())

def main():
    parse_list_page()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I m appreciate you for spending the time to answer my question.

Comment: What data are you after?

Comment: After I run the code, it will return the message below: {'status': False, 'msg': '您操作太频繁,请稍后再访问', 'clientIp': '71.7.186.130', 'state': 2402} , ignore the chinese messages, coz what i know is this website set against web scraping rules    recentenly, I can catch data a few months ago before this rules set. So I don't know what should i do to change this code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, here is the code below:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import requests
from lxml import etree
import time

def parse_list_page():
    url = 'https://www.lagou.com/jobs/list_python?px=default&city=%E6%B7%B1%E5%9C%B3'


    headers = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537',
        'Host':'www.lagou.com',
        'Referer':'https://www.lagou.com/',
        'Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
        'Pragma':'no-cache',
    }

    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    # print(response.text)
    r = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(response.cookies)
    print(r)
    print('='*30)
    # r['LGUID'] = r['LGRID']
    # r['user_trace_token'] = r['LGRID']
    # r['LGSID'] = r['LGRID']

    cookies = {
        # 'X_MIDDLE_TOKEN':'df7c1d3cfdf279f0caf13df990723620',
        # 'JSESSIONID':'ABAAABAAAIAACBI29FE9BDFB6838D8DD69C580E517292C9',
        # '_ga':'GA1.2.820168368.1551196380',
        # '_gat':'1',
        # 'Hm_lvt_4233e74dff0ae5bd0a3d81c6ccf756e6':'1551196381',
        # 'user_trace_token':'20190226235303-99bc357a-39de-11e9-921f-525400f775ce',
        # 'LGSID':'20190311094827-c3bc2393-439f-11e9-a15a-525400f775ce',
        # 'PRE_UTM':'',
        # 'PRE_HOST':'',
        # 'PRE_SITE':'',
        # 'PRE_LAND':'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lagou.com%2F',
        # 'LGUID':'20190226235303-99bc3944-39de-11e9-921f-525400f775ce',
        # '_gid':'GA1.2.1391680888.1552248111',
        # 'index_location_city':'%E6%B7%B1%E5%9C%B3',
        # 'TG-TRACK-CODE':'index_search',
        # 'LGRID':'20190311100452-0ed0525c-43a2-11e9-9113-5254005c3644',
        # 'Hm_lpvt_4233e74dff0ae5bd0a3d81c6ccf756e6':'1552269893',
        # 'SEARCH_ID':'aae3c38ec76545fc86cd4e23153afe44',

    }
    cookies.update(r)

    print(r)
    print('=' * 30)
    print(cookies)
    print('=' * 30)

    headers = {
        'Origin':'https://www.lagou.com',
        'X-Anit-Forge-Code': '0',
        'X-Anit-Forge-Token': None,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'h-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Referer': 'https://www.lagou.com/jobs/list_python?px=default&city=%E6%B7%B1%E5%9C%B3',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    }

    params = {
        'px':'default',
        'city':'深圳',
        'needAddtionalResult':'false'
    }

    data = {
        'first':'true',
        'pn':1,
        'kd':'python',
    }
    url_json = 'https://www.lagou.com/jobs/positionAjax.json'
    response = requests.post(url=url_json,headers=headers,params=params,cookies=cookies,data=data)
    print(response.json())






def main():
    parse_list_page()





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The reason why I can't get the json as response is the against web scraping rules here is you need to use the first cookie when you send the request.
so when you first send the request you need to save the cookies and then update it to use your second page request. Hope it will helpful for you to do web scraping when you face this problem